# Using Contains<T> method in a ConcurrentQueue if T is a class or structure

Tags: c#, contains, concurrent-queue

I badly understand ConcurentQueue collection. How to use Contains method in a ConcurrentQueue if T is a class or structure?

My code:

```
    namespace lab2Form
    {
        struct DomainName
        {
            public string domainName;
            public ulong domainNameCounter;
        }

        class LogStruct
        {
            public ConcurrentQueue<DomainName> domainNameQueue;
            //some code

            public LogStruct()
            {
                domainNameQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<DomainName>() { };
                //some code
            }
        }

        class CLogParser
        {
            LogStruct m_logStruct;

            public CLogParser()
            {
                 m_logStruct = new LogStruct();
            }

            public void ThreadProc(object param)
            {
                //...
                string line;
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var space_pos = line.IndexOf(' ');
                    if (space_pos > 0)
                    {
                      string[] parameters = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' },            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                      string domainName = parameters[0];
                      if (m_logStruct.domainNameQueue.Contains<DomainName>(domainName))//I can't understand how to build this code-string correctly
                      {
                      }
               //...
}
```

How to use contains method in concurrentqueue correctly?

Comment: [ConncurrentQueue(T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) also here is the .Contains Example [.Contains() ConncurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  We don't even know why you're checking whether the queue contains `domainName`; are you trying to avoid the same name being enqueued twice?  Where does the queue get emptied?  What's the purpose of `domainNameCounter`, and does it matter that your design won't allow you to update it for items already in the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string while Contains method expects a DomainName. This should compile:

```
m_logStruct.domainNameQueue.Contains<DomainName>(new DomainName {domainName = domainName})
```

However this won't be very useful if you want to check for domainName equality. You can override Equals in DomainName:

```
struct DomainName
{
    public string domainName;
    public ulong domainNameCounter;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is DomainName)
        {
            return ((DomainName) obj).domainName == domainName;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only match a DomainName member where the other field, domainNameCounter, is 0. However, this could be made to work if a) the input "parameters" actually has a domainNameCounter value to use (parsed from the string to ulong of course), and b) the new object for comparison includes that value (i.e. "new DomainName { domainName = domainName, domainNameCounter = domainNameCounter }")

Comment: Re: edit for Equals override: if you don't want to actually override the struct's built-in comparison, you could use the Contains(T, IEqualityComparer<T>) overload instead. E.g. ".Contains(new DomainName { domainName = domainName }, Comparer.Create((d1, d2) => d1.domainName == d2.domainName))". Of course by the time one's gone to that much trouble, I think the Any() method is easier. :) Also note that there should not be any need to provide the type parameter for whichever method is used; type inference should do the right thing here.

Answer (score 2):

Try `m_logStruct.domainNameQueue.Any(d => d.domainName == domainName)`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to consider `domainName` field as uniquely identifying field in your queue then override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` like:

```
struct DomainName : IEquatable<DomainName>
{
    public string domainName;
    public ulong domainNameCounter;

    public bool Equals(DomainName other)
    {
        return string.Equals(domainName, other.domainName);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        return obj is DomainName && Equals((DomainName) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (domainName != null ? domainName.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

and then you can do:

```
LogStruct m_logStruct = new LogStruct();
m_logStruct.domainNameQueue.Enqueue(new DomainName() {domainName = "ABC", domainNameCounter = 1});
m_logStruct.domainNameQueue.Enqueue(new DomainName() {domainName = "DEF", domainNameCounter = 1});

if (m_logStruct.domainNameQueue.Contains(new DomainName() {domainName = "ABC", domainNameCounter = 1}))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Already exists");
}
```

Otherwise `Contains` will only compare the references.

If you want to include both fields `domainName` and `domainNameCounter` then include both fields in `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementation.

If you don't want to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` then you can't use `Contains` *(without `IEqualityComparer<DomainName>`)* instead you have to loop through your queue and check if any item's `domainName` matches your new `domainName`. Through LINQ you can do that using:

```
bool ifExist = m_logStruct.domainNameQueue.Any(d => d.domainName == domainName);
```

*(like specified in @Peter Duniho's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26473256/961113))*

Comment: @MikeStrobel, sure that can be added as `Equals(T)` is implemented, but there is no need for it with `Contains`

Comment: @MikeStrobel, fair enough. I added it.

Comment: "If you don't want to override Equals and GetHashCode then you can't use Contains": note that you can use Contains, you just have to provide an IEqualityComparer<T> implementation along with the reference object to look for.